# Beginner GraphQL & Drupal - Static Query returns TypeError: Cannot read property 'allNodeData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drupal, graphql, gatsby

I am new to Graphql but can not query anything in GraphQL from Drupal with Static Query/ useStaticQuery. Page Querying works fine, however, I'm looking to avoid the limitation of working from within pages.

Gatsby-source-drupal is connected and I can see fields populate in localhost/___graphql.

Static Query works fine when I have information hardcoded in Gatsby-config.js module.exports. When not, I receive the same error over and over no matter where or in what type of configuration.

Any tips would be much appreciated

```
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import { useHeaderImg } from "../../hooks/use-header-images.js"

import "./header.css"

function Header({ siteTitle }) {
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            description
            author
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )
  const { format, processed, value } = useHeaderImg()
  return (
    <header className="rebeccapurple">
      <h3> This is a variable {format}</h3>
      <div className="purpz">
        <h1 className="zero">
          <Link className="link" to="/">
            {siteTitle} Woah {site.siteMetadata.author}
          </Link>
        </h1>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}
Header.propTypes = {
  siteTitle: PropTypes.string,
}

Header.defaultProps = {
  siteTitle: ``,
}

export default Header
```

```
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

// Based off "Composing custom useStatic hooks"
export const useHeaderImg = () => {
  const { data } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query HeaderImgData {
        allNodeBelvedereBanner {
          edges {
            node {
              field_header {
                format
                processed
                value
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )
  return data.allNodeBelvedereBanner.edges.node.field_header
}
```

The static query above in my Header component works because I have the siteMetadata coded in module.exports within gatsby-config. If I try to query anything from drupal the same way, it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/#basic-example) you shouldn't need to destructure `data` so `data` is going to be `undefined`.

Have you tried this?

```
export const useHeaderImg = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query HeaderImgData {
        allNodeBelvedereBanner {
          edges {
            node {
              field_header {
                format
                processed
                value
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )
  return data.allNodeBelvedereBanner.edges.node.field_header
}
```

Comment: Great! That does take me one step further in the tree; now, my error is returning as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'field_header' of undefined.`

Mind you, graphql should be returning this 

```{
  "data": {
    "allNodeBelvedereBanner": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "field_header": {
              "format": "basic_html",
              "processed": "Blvdr Header",
              "value": "Blvdr Header"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}```

Comment: If that's the data, then `edges` is an array: `data.allNodeBelvedereBanner.edges[0].node.field_header`

Comment: lmfao, I am so relieved that I'm just dumb and this is not something worse. Thank you for your help!!